# How to crop a polygon from BufferedImage

Tags: java, java-6, graphics2d

How to crop a polygon shaped portion of BufferedImage and write it to another BufferedImage?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific than that. In an image, lots of shapes can be "mistaken" for a polygon. Or do you already know what polygon/kind of polygon you're going to crop?

Comment: @Ricardo Ferreira I don't know how can I be more specific than saying "polygon." Need to crop a "portion of image enclosed in a path of  finite sequence of straight lines?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graphics2D has clip(Shape) and draw(Shape) methods. So I would guess you can set the Shape to be your polygon and then paint from one BufferedImage to the other.