# Pixel Count in Java

Tags: java, graphics, colors, pixel, bufferedimage

Ok, after battling for the entire afternoon, I cant seem to get the right answer.
Basically, I have a very simple setup that fills my canvas, a BufferedImage, with a white background. I then draw a Polygon from points coming from my args array. Display-wise, this works perfectly. The problem comes in when I want to count the number of pixels the Polygon (which is filled), uses up.

To do this, I looped through the canvas and compared each pixel using the getRGB method, and if it wasn't white (the background color), I incremented a counter. However, the result I always get is the dimension of the canvas (640*480) which means the entire canvas is white.

So I'm assuming the Polygon that gets drawn to the screen isn't added to the canvas, and is floating on top? Thats the the only answer I can come up with, but could be entirely wrong.

What I'd like is to be able to count the number of pixels that aren't white. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
public class Application extends JPanel {

public static int[] xCoord = null;
public static int[] yCoord = null;
private static int xRef = 250;
private static int yRef = 250;
private static int xOld = 0;
private static int yOld = 0;
private static BufferedImage canvas;
private static Polygon poly;

public Application(int width, int height) {
    canvas = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    fillCanvas(Color.WHITE);
    poly = new Polygon(xCoord, yCoord, xCoord.length);     

    //Loop through each pixel
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < canvas.getWidth(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < canvas.getHeight(); j++) {
            Color c = new Color(canvas.getRGB(i, j));
            if (c.equals(Color.WHITE))
                count++;
        }
    System.out.println(count);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(canvas, null, null);
    g2.fillPolygon(poly);

}

public void fillCanvas(Color c) {
    int color = c.getRGB();
    for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < canvas.getHeight(); y++) {
            canvas.setRGB(x, y, color);
        }
    }
    repaint();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {       
    if (args != null)
        findPoints(args);

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Draw");
    Application panel = new Application(640, 480);

    window.add(panel);
    Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(640, 480);
    window.setPreferredSize(SIZE);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.pack();    
}//end main
```

The method 'findPoints(args)' is too long to post, but basically all it does it takes the argument values and compiles a list of points.

Thanks in advance,
Boots

Comment: The shape interface has a `getBounds()` method that would be useful here. Since the Polygon is filled in you can use the `getBounds()` method to see how much of the canvas the polygon occupies and do subtraction to get its size in pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an exclamation mark to invert the boolean value inside your condition:

```
if (!c.equals(Color.WHITE))
```

A faster way is to check the rgb value instead of first creating a Color object of it:

```
if ((rgb & 0xFFFFFF) != 0xFFFFFF)
```

---

Create a BufferedImage, draw the polygon, and count. Basically, this:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
g.fill(polygon);
g.dispose();
countThePixels(img);
```

Comment: This still won't help solving the OP's intent -- the polygon is not counted

Comment: Forgot to adjust that, was origionally that. As Attila said, it doesnt count the polygon

Comment: Thanks, any info on your code? I don't understand how img is affected? Surely g is filled with a polygon, but that doesnt affect img?

Answer (score 0):

When you create/fill the canvas, you are working with a `BufferedImage` object.  The poligon is captured in a `Polygon` object.  The actual rendering to the screen is done manipulating a `Graphics` object -- so in a sense the polygon is "floating"; that is: it does not show up on the canvas, but is painted on top of it when the Graphics object is rendered.

You will need to actually render the polygon on the canvas itself, or get the pixels from the Graphics object and perform your calculation on that

Comment: How would I render the polygon on the canvas?

Comment: You could try the approach outlined in this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997473/how-to-crop-a-polygon-from-bufferedimage)

Comment: Tried looking at that thread, couldn't get anything useful from it.

Comment: You can create a Graphics2D [from a BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#createGraphics(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)) (your `canvas`), then call fill() on that Graphics2d object with your polygon -- it should draw the filled polygon onto the BufferedImage (your canvas)